When is $M[\mathscr{U}]\cap2^\omega=M\cap2^\omega$?
Suppose that $M$ is a countable, transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{P}(\omega)^M$ is an $M$-generic $M$-ultrafilter (say, $\mathscr{U}\in M[G]$ some $(M,\mathbb{P})$-generic filter $G$). When is $\mathscr{P}(\omega)^{M[\mathscr{U}]}=\mathscr{P}(\omega)^M$?
Since $\mathscr{U}$ is $M$-generic we can identify it with the generic filter for some $\mathbb{Q}$ that completely embeds into $\mathbb{P}$, and so we are done: $\mathscr{P}(\omega)^{M[\mathscr{U}]}=\mathscr{P}(\omega)^M$ if and only if there is some condition in the $(M,\mathbb{Q})$-generic given by $\mathscr{U}$ below which $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\sigma$-distributive. However, this is not a very 'workable' answer. Instead, I would like to focus on properties of $\mathscr{U}$ itself that would indicate this behaviour.
For example, as Will Brian has mentioned in the comments, both Mathias and Silver forcings exhibit this sort of behaviour: Each can be factorised into $\mathbb{P}\ast\mathbb{Q}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is a $\sigma$-closed forcing adding a Ramsey ultrafilter on $\omega$. It is this sort of property that I would like to generalise.
A particular case that I am interested in is when we have an $M$-generic set $x\subseteq\omega$ and $\mathscr{U}$ is in some way 'definable from $x$' in a canonical way. In the example of Mathias forcing, if $x$ is the Mathias real then $\mathscr{U}=\{y\in\mathscr{P}(\omega)^M\mid x\subseteq^\ast y\}$. Here $\mathscr{U}$ is Ramsey and $\mathscr{P}(\omega)^{M[\mathscr{U}]}=\mathscr{P}(\omega)^M$. Is Ramsey enough? If so, could we weaken this to being a P-point?

If $\mathscr{U}$ is an $M$-generic $M$-ultrafilter, then isn't it an $M$-generic filter for some forcing $\mathbb{P}$ in $M$? Then is your question equivalent to that $\mathbb{P}$ does not add reals?

@HanulJeon: If I'm understanding the question right, I think $\mathcal U$ is meant to be an ultrafilter on $\omega$, not on some forcing poset. For example, the Mathias or Silver forcings each have a factorization into two posets, of the form (sigma-closed)*(ccc), where the sigma-closed poset adds a Ramsey ultrafilter on $\omega$ and then the ccc poset adds a real. If $\mathcal U$ is this ultrafilter (and we're forcing over $M$), then $M[\mathcal U]$ contains no new reals, even though $M[G]$ does, because $M[\mathcal U]$ only sees the sigma-centered part of the forcing.

@WillBrian If your understanding is right, then the OP should discard the expression '$\mathscr{U}$ is an $M$-generic' which is confusing... Or we may state the question like "Is there an ultrafilter $U$ over $\omega$ added by forcing, but adding $U$ does not add any reals."

@HanulJeon I think it is fairly common to say that a set is generic over a model to mean that it belongs to some generic extension of that model.

@HanulJeon Yes, but I would like to focus on the properties of $\mathscr{U}$ itself that guarantee that $\mathscr{U}$ does not add reals, rather than the forcing from which it came. Question edited for clarity.

I am not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for a sufficient (in some sense "local" and/or "combinatorial")  condition on U guaranteeing that M[U] and M have the same reals, and conjecture that "U Ramsey" is sufficient? (It is certainly not necessary.)

@Goldstern Correct

I don't think that "U Ramsey" is enough. I will construct a model $M[G]$ in which there is

a new real $x\in 2^\omega\setminus M$
a Ramsey ultrafilter U (which lives on $2^{<\omega}$ instead of $\omega$, but that is not a problem)

such that $x\in M[U]$.
First let $x$ be any new real, e.g. a Cohen real.  Now let $A:= \{x\restriction n: n\in \omega\} \subseteq 2^{<\omega}$. Now use Mathias forcing in M[x] to add a Mathias subset $g\subseteq A$.  The set $g$ induces a Ramsey ultrafilter on $A$, but also a Ramsey ultrafilter $U$ on $2^{<\omega}$.
For each $s\in 2^{<\omega}$ let $[s]:=\{t\in 2^{<\omega}: s \subseteq t\}$. This is the tree $    2^{<\omega}$ above $s$.
For all $s\in 2^{<\omega}$ we have $s\in A \Rightarrow [s] \supseteq^* A$, and $s\notin A \Rightarrow [s] \cap A=\emptyset$.
Hence $s\in A \Leftrightarrow [s]\in U$.   So $A$ can be computed from $U$, hence also $x\in L[U]$.
